# App breaks in IE11 with IE=edge

Tags: angularjs

We have a fairly complex application that has been working perfectly fine in all browsers (chrome, firefox, safari, IE <= 10) and we just tried to test it in IE 11 and it simply doesn't work at all with no errors thrown. We have the correct meta tag for the document mode setting IE=edge. When I change this to IE=10 the application works fine.

We are using angular 1.2.0 and without getting into the specifics of the application has anyone experienced this before and if so, do you know why this happens? When this goes into production we need to be using IE=edge.

Comment: You will probably need to include more info to get a real solution.  What other 3rd party libraries are you using?  For example, I've had problems with IE11 and jQuery 1.10 because of some removed methods.

Comment: I don't get any errors in the console, and it seems as if angular isn't even parsing the page (all of the "{{}}" bindings aren't being replaced), yet it must be getting bootstrapped because I can see the request for templates (partials) being made, etc

Comment: We are using other libraries, such as angular-segment for routing, and we are using jquery, but I find it odd that there aren't any errors thrown